# C# Windows.Forms.Timer doesnt work properly

Tags: winforms

I have some troubles while making simple application on C# / Windows.Forms that simulates a pendulum.

It's a simple application with all backend logic in form code.
First of all, I set up the interval equals 100 milliseconds (line 60), but when I calculate number of turns (line 155) and display it, displaying message:

1. refresh every second (not every 100 milliseconds)
2. and it behaves like this: 1-2-4-5-6-8 or 1-3-4-5-7-8 etc.

I don't know when it started bugging and want to determine the mistake.

Thanks a lot for your help.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Koban_Lab1
{
public partial class mainWindow : Form
{
    public Point pendFulcrum = new Point(150, 0);
    public Point pendTip = new Point();
    private bool deviceState_;
    private long ticks_;
    private DateTime startTiming;
    private Pen blackPencil;
    public static double g = 9.8;
    public double T;
    public double periodInTicks;
    public double L;
    public double a;
    public double Amp;
    public double startOffset;
    public double w;
    public double periodCounter;
    public double x;
    public double y;
    public double currentAngle;

    private Timer timer_;
    public double t;

    public Bitmap field;

    private long cnt = 0;
    private bool DeviceState
    {
        get
        {
            return deviceState_;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == deviceState_)
            {
                return;
            }

            deviceState_ = value;
            switch (value)
            {
                case true:
                    L = Convert.ToDouble(pendulumLengthTextBox.Text) / 100;
                    a = Convert.ToDouble(plummetDistanceTextBox.Text) / 100;
                    periodCounter = 0;
                    T = 2 * Math.PI * Math.Sqrt((L * L) / (12 * g * a) + a / g);
                    w = 2 * Math.PI / T;
                    Amp = 2 * Math.PI * L / 24;
                    startOffset = Amp;
                    startTiming = DateTime.Now;
                    timer_ = new Timer();
                    timer_.Interval = 100;
                    timer_.Tick += new EventHandler(tickTimer);
                    timer_.Start();
                    startPendulumButton.Enabled = false;
                    stopPendulumButton.Enabled = true;
                    pendulumLengthTextBox.Enabled = false;
                    plummetDistanceTextBox.Enabled = false;
                    addReadoutButton.Enabled = true;
                    break;
                case false:
                    timer_.Stop();
                    timer_ = null;
                    startPendulumButton.Enabled = true;
                    stopPendulumButton.Enabled = false;
                    pendulumLengthTextBox.Enabled = true;
                    plummetDistanceTextBox.Enabled = true;
                    timerTextBox1.Text = Locale.timerDisabledMessage;
                    timerTextBox2.Text = "0";
                    addReadoutButton.Enabled = false;
                    break;
            }

            return;
        }
    }

    public Graphics fieldGraphics;

    public mainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pendulumLengthTooltip.SetToolTip(pendulumLengthTextBox, Locale.pendulumLengthTooltipMessage);
        plummetDistanceTooltip.SetToolTip(plummetDistanceTextBox, Locale.plummetDistanceTooltipMessage);
        blackPencil = Pens.Gray;
        timerTextBox1.Text = Locale.timerDisabledMessage;
        timerTextBox2.Text = "0";
        deleteReadoutButton.Enabled = false;
        DeviceState = false;
        field = new Bitmap(pendulumField.Width, pendulumField.Height);
    }

    private void startPendulumButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DeviceState = true;
    }

    private void stopPendulumButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DeviceState = false;
    }

    private void addReadoutButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (timerTextBox1.Text == Locale.timerDisabledMessage)
        {
            return;
        }

        readoutList.Items.Add(timerTextBox1.Text);
        deleteReadoutButton.Enabled = true;

        return;
    }

    private void deleteReadoutButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (readoutList.SelectedIndex != (-1))
        {
            readoutList.Items.RemoveAt(readoutList.SelectedIndex);
        }
        else
        {
            readoutList.Items.RemoveAt(readoutList.Items.Count - 1);
        }

        if (readoutList.Items.Count == 0)
        {
            deleteReadoutButton.Enabled = false;
        }
    }



    private void tickTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ticks_ = DateTime.Now.Ticks - startTiming.Ticks;
        timerTextBox1.Text = TimeSpan.FromTicks(ticks_).ToString(@"mm\:ss\:ff");
        timerTextBox2.Text = periodCounter.ToString();

        ticks_ = DateTime.Now.Ticks - startTiming.Ticks;
        t = ticks_ / TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond;
        periodCounter = t / T;
        timerTextBox2.Text = Convert.ToInt32(periodCounter).ToString();


        currentAngle = Amp * Math.Sin(w * t);
        x = x * Math.Cos(currentAngle) - y * Math.Sin(currentAngle);
        y = x * Math.Sin(currentAngle) + y * Math.Cos(currentAngle);

        Program.labWindow.fieldGraphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(Program.labWindow.pendulumField.Handle);
        pendTip.X = (int)x;
        pendTip.Y = (int)y;
        fieldGraphics.DrawLine(blackPencil, pendFulcrum, pendTip);

        pendulumField.Image = field;
        Application.DoEvents();
    }

    private void plummetDistanceTooltip_Popup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void plummetDistanceLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Here are some points: 1) Line numbers are not available in StackOverflow. Either break your code into sections or add comment "labels". 2) Timers are a bad way to implement periodic actions since they are not accurate. If your TimerTick code takes long to execute that will distort your timing. 3) Try to trim away code segments that are irrelevant for demonstrating the problem. 4) Your description at the of what is going wrong is not clear. Please be more exact and format it better.

Comment: i will post another question, thank you

Comment: Instead another question, You can edit this same question